# Consolidate the dataframe to plot line graph in R

Tags: r

I have a frequency table, describing the lengths, which I would like to plot as a line graph preferably using ggplot2. But the table has 13373 observations, which makes it difficult to plot all the points. So is there any way I can consolidate the plot to less number of observations to get a good looking plot.

The head of the dataframe

```
  Length Freq
1  151    1
2  152    1
3  159    1
4  168    2
5  174    1
6  177    1
```

The summary of the length variable:

```
 Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
    151    1692    4624    9795    9921  834300
```

I am basically looking for a plot similar to this [image: line chart]

Thanks a lot,
Karthic K

Comment: Could you add some details for your desired output? Which variable you'd like on the x and y axis? Are there any group (like D.melanogaster etc in your example) and if so, could you add them on your example of data?

Comment: Your question is outside the scope of this side. However, a suggestion that comes to mind is do a k-means clustering and plot the clusters centers...? But it all depends on your usecase and what you want to do with the results

Comment: Your question is unclear. It shouldn't be a problem plotting--and visualizing--tens of thousands of points in `ggplot2`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I currently do not have groups in my data, i have only single species, so a single line chart. The x-axis should have the Length variable and Y-axis should have Freq variable.

Comment: Can you please show us in what way your plot looks "bad" now? I don't think you need to bin your data at all. Your graph will probably look weirder after you bin your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can! Gene length is basically a numerical variable so you could bin/cut it into groups and aggregate like this:

```r
df %>%
mutate(Length_bin = cut(Length, breaks = 100) %>%
groub_by(Length_bin) %>%
summarise(Freq = sum(Freq))
```

You can define the number of breaks or manually input cut points.

Comment: Hi Fnguyen, I have tried your solution .. but getting the error Error: Evaluation error: no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "factor".

Comment: Got it. It was a closing brace issue. My data has some extreme values towards the right, so it is making the graph look wierder. Anyway thanks a lot.

Comment: @KarthicdotK maybe you could log-transform the scale if it is an issue of extreme absolute level difference in the x-axis (e.g. you want to see what happens at a length of 1-50 equally well as at a length of 1M-10M) same goes for y-axis of course. Also I added the missing bracket in my example code, sorry for that.